# Wicket: ConverterLocato - Set IConverter for interface

Tags: java, wicket

Apache Wicket-question:

I'm trying to register a IConverter in the ConverterLocator class. From the WebApplication-class:

```
protected IConverterLocator newConverterLocator() {
    ConverterLocator locator = (ConverterLocator) super.newConverterLocator();
    locator.set(MyInterface.class, new MyConverter());      
}
```

My problem is that the MyConverter.convertTo*()-methods are never "triggered" when a value is a class that implements MyInterface. It only works when I'm registering implementations of MyInterface in the ConverterLocator.

Any suggestions on how I can make MyConverter convert all the implementations of MyInterface without having to register them all manually?

This seems like basic polymorphic behaviour :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think that the only solution is to implement your own `IConverterLocator` and override your `WebApplication.newConverterLocator()` to register it.

This is the piece of code that you have to change on the current default implementation:

```
public final <C> IConverter<C> get(Class<C> c)
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    IConverter<C> converter = (IConverter<C>)classToConverter.get(c.getName());
    return converter;
}
```

Take a look at it here:
https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/ConverterLocator.java

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. The code only run during startup so performance should not be an issue. The trick is to find all the implementations of the interface by classpath-scanning with springs ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.

Not very elegant solution though :-)

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(true);
provider.addIncludeFilter(new AssignableTypeFilter(MyInterface.class));


Set<BeanDefinition> components = provider.findCandidateComponents("org/example/package");
for (BeanDefinition component : components)
{
    Class cls = Class.forName(component.getBeanClassName());
    locator.set(cls, new MyGenericConverter<MyInterface>());
}
```

Then overrided the default ConverterLocator and added the code above to the constructor.